# What's the meaning of **for** here?

Tags: phrases

In The Fairy Tale of Father Brown by G. K. Chesterton, the author was talking about a prince returning to his castle through the forest, saying:

“The moon had risen in strengthening silver, and the sky showed in stripes of bright, nocturnal blue between the black stripes of the pines about the castle. Flowers of some wide and feathery sort—**for** he had never noticed such things before—were at once luminous and discoloured by the moonshine, and seemed indescribably fantastic as they clustered, as if crawling about the roots of the trees.

What's the meaning of **for** here?

Comment: It means “because”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["For" with the meaning of "because"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289896/for-with-the-meaning-of-because)

Comment: But what's the reason here for what?

Comment: I can't get the causality here

Comment: It's a literary, broadened usage. More than just 'because'. Try ' – and here I have to explain that he was unfamiliar with flowers [/this sort of flower], and hence could describe them no more precisely –'.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

*For* means *seeing that* or *since* here:

> **for**,  *conj.*
>   **2. a.** Introducing the ground or reason for something previously said: Seeing that, since. Cf. Greek *γάρ*, Latin *nam* or *enim*,
>   French *car*, German *denn*.
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford English
>   Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/) (login required)</sub>

The flowers, rather than being called by their common or botanical name, are described, and that is because he had never seen them before and didn't know what to call them:

> *Flowers of some wide and feathery sort (no name for them—seeing that he had never noticed such things before) were at once luminous and
>   discoloured by the moonshine . . .*

Comment: Thank you so much, that's clearer